# How to add ionic linkedin and google plus native plugin in single ionic project?

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

How to add ionic linkedin and google plus native plugins in ionic3 project in iOS platform. Because there are two Appdelegates in the single iOS ionic project. How to handle this scenario?

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO, please share more context around your question, its presently unclear what the issue is, what errors you are getting and why exactly importing two native plugins presents a problem in Ionic for you.

Comment: I have installed @ionic-native/google-plus and @ionic-native/linkedin in my project. There are two Appdelegates one for google plus and another one for linkedin. Once i logged in thru google plus its working fine, but whereas from linkedin its redirect to google plus appdelegate not to linkedin appdelegate.